# O que fazer quando editarem a pergunta com base no que respondeu?

Tags: suporte, perguntas, respostas

Recentemente respondi uma [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/371256/como-alterar-a-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-meu-bot%C3%A3o-de-salvar-para-alterar/371259?noredirect=1#comment738751_371259), normal e não muito clara, questionando como fazia **X**.

Fui lá e respondi para ele como podia ser feito **X**.

Então, percebi que a pergunta foi editada, e na edição, o questionador colocou o código da minha resposta, já implementada no código, e nisso, perguntou por que dava o erro **Y**, com base na minha resposta. A nova pergunta editada não tem nada ver com o que havia sido questionado antes.

Agora, não sei o que fazer.

Comment: Indicado é fazer o que o Favaretto fez: reverter a edição, pois descaracterizou a pergunta e invalidou as respostas. Mas tome muito cuidado em responder quando está "não muito clara" pois você pode ter entendido errado e quando o AP corrigir a pergunta poderá invalidar a sua resposta (mas por culpa sua).

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss levarei em consideração. O que deu para entender, é que o questionador queria suporte para aquela resposta dada, e já sabemos que isso não é possível em uma única pergunta no SOPT.

Comment: Só tem que tomar cuidado para não virar uma guerra de edição. Se houve mais de uma ou duas interações conflitantes, sinalize para a moderação, para que o problema não escale. Outra coisa que talvez fosse mais adequada se a resposta não resolveu claramente, é votar para fechar a pergunta, e até deletar a resposta caso realmente não tenha conserto e não seja uma solução.

Comment: @Bacco ele acabou de editar novamente e desfazer o que o fez. Eu comentei lá sobre isso na publicação, mas ele não parou. A pergunta já foi fechada.

Comment: Ficou bem confuso o caso. Eu realmente recomendo que quando a pergunta não é clara (não estou afirmando que seja o caso) é melhor aguardar o autor esclarecer do que responder. No caso específico é complicado, pois se foi fechada como não clara, a única solução do autor é editar para esclarecer, ao mesmo tempo que o esclarecimento não deveria incluir uma mudança de sentido (mas as vezes é inevitável)

Comment: A perguntava não estava clara suficiente, mas interpretei o que ele queria fazer. Respondi com base no que foi perguntado, e aparentemente foi solucionado o problema primário. Mas aí ele editou a pergunta com um segundo problema, usando a minha solução como base para resolução.

Comment: Por favor não atirem pedras por fugir da questão levantada. Eu respondi duas perguntas desse mesmo usuário [pergunta 1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/371314/salvar-altera%C3%A7%C3%B5es-no-banco/371379#371379), [pergunta 2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/371435/como-alterar-um-dado-no-bd) e pude verificar outro problema além da questão levantada, que é o que fazer quando o usuário enxerga o SOpt como um forum e força a dinâmica de um forum ignorando o formato do SOpt e qual o protocolo que deve se adotado para que uma simples seção de Q&A não se estenda indefinidamente.

Comment: Aconteceu-me algo semelhante só que, depois de ter editado a pergunta, o OP também a apagou: [Remoção de uma pergunta após esta ter sido respondida](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7859/remo%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-uma-pergunta-ap%c3%b3s-esta-ter-sido-respondida).

Answer (score 8):

Eu reverti a edição, que é o que deve ser feito nesses casos. Também fechei a pergunta, já que ela não é muito clara mesmo.