# Remoção de uma pergunta após esta ter sido respondida

Tags: debate, perguntas, moderação, usuarios

Encontrei uma pergunta em que o erro era a falta de aspas. Respondi a essa pergunta e expliquei o erro na resposta. No entanto, quando o autor da pergunta viu a minha resposta, ele editou a sua pergunta de modo a remover o erro e depois removeu a pergunta. Como só havia uma resposta, a minha, e essa resposta ainda não tinha votos positivos, o autor da pergunta pôde removê-la... por isso ela não pode ver vista pela maior parte do público... (só por ele, por mim, por desenvolvedores, moderadores e pessoas com mais de dez mil pontos de reputação).

A pergunta dever-se-ia encontrar neste link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/396374.

Este tipo de atitudes é aceitável? Parece-me injusto...
Uma captura de ecrã da pergunta e da minha reposta:

> [image: Pergunta]
>   [image: Resposta]

Comment: O nome do site devia mudar de stackoverflow para helpdeskoverflow ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Há cerca de um ano atrás, tinha um cara que fazia umas perguntas em python e depois que eu respondia, ele deletava a pergunta. Depois da terceira vez que ele fez isso, eu postei um comentário na pergunta dele dizendo que eu sabia como responder, mas me recusava a ajudá-lo por ele deletar as perguntas. E o fato de eu ter postado esse comentário, fez com que outras pessoas também se recusassem a responder.

Enfim, o sistema dá o direito a pessoa de apagar a pergunta dela em alguns casos, sobretudo quando a pergunta é nova, não tem votos positivos e nem respostas com votos positivos (não lembro a regra exatamente, mas é algo parecido com isso). Considerando ainda que a pergunta era só um erro de digitação, o certo seria inclusive fechá-la. Por outro lado, para usuários que revelarem-se ser *leechers* ingratos, você tem todo o direito de recusar a responder a pergunta e se tiver reputação o suficiente, postar um comentário explicando isso.

Infelizmente, numa comunidade com tanta gente como o SOpt, inevitavelmente teremos cedo ou tarde algumas frustrações e aborrecimentos com outros usuários mesmo sem ter feito nada errado, mas apesar disso, o mundo continua dando voltas e a vida segue.

Se a pergunta (ou mesmo resposta) deletada for boa, sinalize ela para que algum moderador restaure-a. Se não tiver como acessar/visualizar a pergunta/resposta deletada, tente sinalizar alguma outra postagem da pessoa e explique que uma das perguntas/respostas deletadas daquela pessoa deveria ser restaurada, descrevendo qual é ou então peça ajuda aos usuários mais experientes e aos moderadores no chat para localizar e restaurar a pergunta/resposta.

Answer (score 11):

Neste caso é sim porque o erro é de digitação e não vai ajudar mais ninguém, então a pergunta seria fechada de qualquer forma e talvez até mesmo o sistema a removeria em algum momento. O Stack Overflow é um repositório de soluções para usuários diversos poderem aproveitar no futuro, erro de digitação só ajuda a pessoa em algo pontual, não serve para outras pessoas (eu acho que boa parte das respostas atuais estão resolvendo apenas o problema da pessoa, não a toa que se tornou raro grandes votações em respostas como acontecia antes). Erro de digitação só mostra que tem gente desatenta.

Comment: E se a pergunta pudesse ajudar outros no futuro, se não fosse um erro simples? Seria aceitável apagar a pergunta após se ter lido a resposta?

Comment: Cada caso é um caso, em geral não deveria apagar, mas nem sempre, tem que olhar todos os detalhes.